# Ruby on Rails: How to pass variable between controller functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to use params[:number] from the new function in the create function, how would I go about doing this?

```
def new
   @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new

    @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => params[:number] })
end

def create        
    @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new(params[:test_suite_run])

    @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => //I need the same params[:number] here})   
end
```

EDIT: I guess I am confused as the differences between new and create then. I am taking in the parameter :number by passing it to new.

`new_test_suite_run_path(:number => ts.id)`

I am then using it to generate the form. I don't understand what to do in the create function then. If I remove the create function in the controller, when I submit the form in new, it gives me an error saying that there is no create action in the controller. Does that mean I have to move everything in new to the create function? How would that be possible, would I have to create a create.html.erb and move all my form information?

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive to have both a `new` and `create` function :/ seems like you would need to pass in the original `:number` parameter into both functions from the same place

Comment: Your use of new and create methods are unconventional. Can you tell us what you would like to accomplish? Maybe we can suggest a way of doing what you want, without doing the unconventional way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Flash:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

> The flash provides a way to pass temporary objects between actions.
>   Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next
>   action and then cleared out.

---

```
def new
   @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new
   @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => params[:number] })

   flash[:someval] = params[:number]
end

def create        
    @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new(params[:test_suite_run])

    @tests = Test.find(:all, :conditions => { :test_suite_id => flash[:someval] })   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> I guess I am confused as the differences between new and create then.

Let's address this issue first.

`new` method generates a view for a form where Rails build a TestSuiteRun instance. This instance exists only memory *temporally*.

`create` method takes the data entered in the form, and actually saves the instance created into database *permanently*.

I don't think you need to change your `new` method.

Try changing your `create` method to this.

```
def create
  @test_suite_run = TestSuiteRun.new(params[:test_suite_run])
  @test_suite_run.save
end
```